# Webclient C# get filePath after completing async download

Tags: c#, webclient

I have this method:

```
public void downloadClip()
        {
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                //Download
                wc.DownloadFileCompleted += Wc_DownloadFileCompleted;
                string file_name_ender = @"My\Path";
                wc.DownloadFileAsync(new System.Uri(@downloadUri), file_name_ender);
            }
        }
```

then I have this DownloadFileCompleted:

```
private void Wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //I need to get where file was downloaded to
        }
```

I then need to get inside this method string that says where I downloaded my file. Basically my `file_name_ender`.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the second overload method:

```
wc.DownloadFileAsync(uri, file_name_ender, file_name_ender);
```

Then you can get the value from the UserState property in the event:

```
private void Wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var filename = (string)e.UserState;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this answear was helpfull and very nicely managed :))